# What is the meaning of $\|\cdot\|$

Tags: notation, normed-spaces

I am reading a paper, and I saw the following symbol

$\|\cdot\|$ in it. I understand that the vertical bars mean norm. But the dot inside is is confusing me.

The rest of the paragraph reads

> We denote $\|\cdot\|_Q$ by $l_q$.
>   However, be careful: $l_q$ is not a norm.
>   Subadditivity (triangular inequality) is the only one of the
>   three properties required by a norm, which is satisfied by $lq$.

Comment: what could dot signify here

Comment: It means the norm as a function, $K,\|.\|$ means "the normed space [...] "

Comment: The dot indicates where the argument is plugged in. If we would write $\norm{x}$ this would be considered as the norm evaluated at $x$ whereas $\norm{\cdot}$ denotes the map itself.

Comment: Reuns, thanks, can you write it as an answer, so that i can upvote

Comment: In order to notify someone in a comment you need to precede his user name with @. You as a post owner are always notified if someone leaves a comment.

Answer (score 6):

The usual convention in mathematics is to name functions by single letters or short abbreviations, then put the argument of the function in parentheses to the right of the function's name.  For example, if $f$ is a function defined on some domain, then the value of $f$ at some point $x$ is written $f(x)$.

However, there are times when this notation is inconvenient.  For example, suppose that $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.  The usual convention would be to write $f(x,y)$ to denote the value of $f$ at the point $(x,y)$.  But sometimes we want to consider $f$ as a function of just a single variable—for example, when computing the partial derivative $f_x$, we think of $y$ as a fixed constant.  If we want to emphasize the fact that $f$ doesn't really depend on $y$, but retain our usual notation, then we might write
$$ f(\cdot,y) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}.$$
The dot indicates the place where the variable is "plugged in."  Similarly, if we have a normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, then the norm function is a function
$$ \|\cdot\| : X \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} $$
which, when evaluated at $x$, is written $\|x\|$, rather than $\|\,\|(x)$ or $\|\cdot\|(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Usually every mathematician writes $|| \cdot ||$ instead of $||\;||$. The norm $|| \cdot ||$ is actually a  function. One always write $||x||$ instead of $||\cdot||(x)$

So the dot in the middle denote just  the argument as mentioned in the comment!